# Converting an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I convert an array to a form I need cdata to newcdata:

My array is of this format.

```
var cdata = [
{ name: "Apple", count:1, data: 145 }, 
{ name: "Pear", count:1, data: 185 }, 
{ name: "Apple", count:2, data: 245 }, 
{ name: "Pear", count:2, data: 285 }, 
{ name: "Apple", count:3, data: 345 },
{ name: "Pear", count:3, data: 385 }
];
```

I need the array to be in this format. How do I convert it?

```
var newcdata = [
{
    name: "Apple",
    data:[[1,145],[2,245],[3,345]]
},{
    name: "Pear",
    data:[[1,185],[2,285],[3,385]]
}
]
```

Comment: @charlietfl, if this is a duplicate, can you please provide me the actual issue link for my reference please.

Comment: All the answers in that duplicate to what you want. Just the property names are different

Comment: @charlietfl, I updated my question. Can you please help me with the new one.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/azhjswno/4/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!! Worked like a charm.